# Trigger animation on a div when 'space' key is pressed

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm a beginner and I've been trying to figure out how to trigger a CSS animation `('animate__bounceOut')` class on a div when the **space bar** is pressed on my Next.js app.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
const startContainer = window.fetch('#startContainer');

  function handleKeyDown (e) {
    if (e.code ==='Space' || e.key === " ") {
      e.preventDefault();
      return true;
    }
  }

  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown(true));
    return () => {
      startContainer.classList.add('animate__bounceOut');
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    }
  }
)

  return (
    <div class="rootContainer">
      <div id="startContainer" tabIndex={0} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}></div>
      {/*svg inside*/}
    </div>
```

On web, the SVG is shown, but nothing happens when the space bar is pressed. I tried using `useState` initially too (as below), but it produced the same result anyway (no change, just an SVG)

```
const {spacePressed, setSpacePressed} = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    function handleKeyDown(e) {
      if (e.code === 'Space') {
        setSpacePressed(true); {/*note: this returns an error, "setSpacePressed is not a function"*/}
      }
    }
...
return (
    <div class="rootContainer">
      <div id="startContainer" tabIndex={0} className={`$(spacePressed ? 'animate__bounceOut' : '')`}></div>
      {/*svg inside*/}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.fetch` is for fetching resources not getting element references. You probably meant to use `document.querySelector` there.

That `classList.add` call should be there in `handleKeyDown`, not in the `useEffect` cleanup. Also, an empty dependency array should be specified there on `useEffect`.

`onKeyDown` and `tabIndex` aren't needed as you're using a global keydown handler.

It should be `handleKeyDown` in `addEventListener`, not `handleKeyDown(true)`, or you probably meant `true` as the third parameter: `window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true)` (might not be required though).

---

In the second part, it should be array destructuring not object in `useState` call, i.e., it should be like `const [state, setState] = useState(...)`.

Comments in JS part of JSX can't be written like `{/* ... */}` You can either use `//` or `/* ... */`.

For template substitution, you need to do `${...}` not `$(...)`. Also, that's not needed here. You simply can have `classList={spacePressed ? '...': ''}`

---

Solution:

```
const [spacePressed, setSpacePressed] = useState(false);

function handleKeyDown(e) {
  if (e.code === 'Space' || e.key === ' ') {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSpacePressed(true);
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
  };
}, []);

return <div className={spacePressed ? 'animate__bounceOut' : ''}>...</div>;
```